# PowerShell convert Char Array to string

Tags: powershell-3.0

I've read various methods for converting a char array to a string in PowerShell, but none of them seem to work with my string.
The source of my string is:

```
$ComputerName = "6WMPSN1"
$WarrantyURL = "http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/au/en/aulca1/TroubleShooting/ProductSelected/ServiceTag/$ComputerName"
$WarrantyPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $WarrantyURL
$WPageText = $WarrantyPage.AllElements | Where-Object {$_.id -eq "TopContainer"} | Select-Object outerText
```

The resulting WPageText is an Char Array so I can't use Select-String -Pattern "days" -Context

I've tried:

```
$WPageText -join
[string]::Join("", ($WPageText))
```

as per
http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.com.au/2007/12/powershell-string-and-char-sort-and.html

The only things I have been successful with so far is:

```
$TempFile = New-Item -ItemType File -Path $env:Temp -Name $(Get-Random)
$WPageText | Out-File -Path $TempFile
$String = Get-Content -Path $TempFile
```

Any way to do this aside from writing and reading a file?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `-join` operator (with extra parts to prove datatypes):

```
$x = "Hello World".ToCharArray();
$x.GetType().FullName         # returns System.Char[]
$x.Length                     # 11 as that's the length of the array
$s = -join $x                 # Join all elements of the array
$s                            # Return "Hello World"
$s.GetType().FullName         # returns System.String
```

Alternatively, the join can also be written as:

```
$x -join ""
```

Both are legal; `-join` without an LHS just merges the array on its RHS. The second format joins the LHS using the RHS as the delimiter. See [help about_Join](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847757.aspx) for more.

Comment: +1, but I don't see any need to explicitly cast $x to a char array. A much simpler "-join $x" works fine for me.

Comment: It might be a hangover from earlier versions of Powershell - I honestly don't know; I just saw this method advised somewhere some time back.

Answer (score 10):

The cheap shot way of doing this is by modifying the `$ofs` variable and enclosing the array in a string. `$ofs` is an internal PS separator for printing arrays using `Object.ToString()` from .NET.

```
$a = "really cool string"
$c = $a.ToCharArray()
$ofs = '' # clear the separator; it is ' ' by default
"$c"
```

You can (should) also use the `System.String` constructor like this:

```
$a = "another mind blowing string"
$result = New-Object System.String ($a,0,$a.Length)
```

Comment: ++ for the `$OFS` info; worth recommending _localizing_ the `$OFS` change, e.g.: `& { $OFS=''; "$c" }`. Note that even though the _effective_ default is a single space, the _variable_ `$OFS` is by default _not defined_. Not sure what you're recommending regarding the string constructor; `$result = $a` does the same thing much simpler and more efficiently.

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way to convert the char array to a string:

```
[String]::new($WPageText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your are looking for, I think that you miss something concerning `$WPageText`. if you have a look it's a `PSCustomObject` inside which you are interested in `outerText` which is a string.

```
PS C:\PowerShell> $WPageText | Get-Member

   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                                                                                           ----        ----------   ----------                                              
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                                               
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                                            
GetType     Method       type GetType()                                                                                                                                               
ToString    Method       string ToString()                                                                                                                                            
outerText   NoteProperty System.String outerText= ...
```

So

```
PS C:\PowerShell> $WPageText.outerText 

 Precision M6500 
Service Tag: 6WMPSN1 

 Select A Different Product > 
Warranty Information 
Warranty information for this product is not available.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$NewFilename = "77gy-092722-gra" 

$JobArray = $NewFilename.Split("-")

$JobArrayFirstBlock = $JobArray[0].ToCharArray()
   
$Result = "" 

foreach($Character in $JobArrayFirstBlock) 
{ 
   $Result = $Result+$Character.ToString()
}
```