# Get-ChildItem creates blank space in Folder names

Tags: powershell, robocopy, get-childitem

I'm trying to copy files from folders to new folders with same names (Ex: Doc0001/file1.png to a Doc0001 folder created elsewhere).
For an unknown reason, when I copy those files instead of copying them in the new (declared) folder it creates a new folder with spaces in the name i.e "D o c 0 0 0 1".

[image]

Do you know why is that and how to avoid this behaviour ? (I don't mind if it recreates the folder, just with the right names).

Thanks

[P.S] Here is my code so far:

```
Write-Host "Start"

cd D:\Dev\powershell_tools

$Folder = ".\test_2\"
$Destination = ".\test\"

foreach ($folder_path in Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Folder -Recurse -Name -Filter Doc*)
{
 
  $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $($Folder+$folder_path) -name
  $trash = ($folder_path)[-7..-1].Where({$_.Length})
  
  robocopy $($Folder+$folder_path) $($Destination+$trash) $file /lev:1

 }
Write-Host "End"
```

Comment: ($folder_path)[-7..-1] <= this converts the string to a char array, that's where the spaces are coming from.

Comment: Alright I didn't see that. I resolved the issue using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738121/powershell-convert-char-array-to-string

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As bluuf said, your `$folder_path` string is converted to a char array.

With the cmdlet `Copy-File`, you can actually create a destination folder and copy recursively files from the source folder to it :

```
Write-Host "Start"

Set-Location D:\Dev\powershell_tools

$Source = ".\test\"
$Destination = ".\test_2\"

foreach($folder in Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Source -Recurse -Filter "Doc*"){
    if(Test-Path $Destination$($folder.Name)){
        Copy-Item -Path "$($folder.FullName)\*" -Destination $Destination$($folder.Name) -Recurse
    } else {
        Copy-Item -Path $folder.FullName -Destination $Destination$($folder.Name) -Recurse
    }
    
}

Write-Host "End"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Your code doesn't fully work though, it copies a file **and** a folder containing the other 2 files inside a desired folder.

Comment: Are you not trying to replicate the content of $Source in $Destination ?

Comment: Not exactly. Refer to here to get full understanding of the problem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73233175/reorganize-files-using-powershell-script

Comment: To be more precise, I have this structure of file: BATCH/CHANNEL_1/Doc0001/img_1.png and I have several CHANNEL_x containing several Doc000x containing only one image each. 
I want all the images from Doc0001 folder (from all the CHANNEL_x folder) to go a new and unique Doc0001 folder (and same for images in Doc0002, Doc0003 etc...)

Do you think it's doable with Copy-Item ?

Comment: Yes but then there is 2 different cases. The first is when a Docxxxx folder is not existing in the destination folder and the second when a Docxxxx folder is already existing in the destination folder. You can have a look at Microsoft documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.2). I've edited my code to take this nuance into account.

Comment: Awesome ! works like a charm and it's more elegant than my own ^^ Thanks a lot !